# SonicWALL - frequent reboots

Tags: sonicwall

I have a SonicWALL TZ 215 with firmware version 5.8.1.9-43o that frequently reboots itself. In the past 3 months there were 20 restarts of this device. Is this normal? I guess not...

In the logs I could not find anything useful, thus I configured the log options to send an email daily. Unfortunatelly, when the device reboots, all the logs between midnight (time of the email notification) and the reboot are lost.

These are the logs following the reboot (nothing interesting to me):

```
12/16/2015 06:38:36.000 Info    Firewall Event  Network Security Appliance initializing              
12/16/2015 06:38:40.160 Alert   Firewall Event  Interface X0 Link Is Up              
12/16/2015 06:38:40.160 Alert   Firewall Event  Interface X1 Link Is Down                
12/16/2015 06:38:40.160 Alert   Firewall Event  Interface X2 Link Is Down                
12/16/2015 06:38:40.160 Alert   Firewall Event  Interface X3 Link Is Up              
12/16/2015 06:38:40.160 Alert   Firewall Event  Interface X4 Link Is Down                
12/16/2015 06:38:40.160 Alert   Firewall Event  Interface X5 Link Is Down                
12/16/2015 06:38:40.176 Alert   Firewall Event  Interface X6 Link Is Down                
12/16/2015 06:38:40.176 Alert   Firewall Event  Interface U0 Link Is Down                
12/16/2015 06:38:40.176 Alert   Firewall Event  Interface U1 Link Is Down                
12/16/2015 06:38:40.880 Critical    Firewall Event  DHCP Server sanity check passed in initial checking
12/16/2015 06:38:44.144 Alert   Firewall Event  Interface X1 Link Is Up
12/16/2015 06:38:44.144 Alert   WAN Availability    WLB Resource is now available   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, 0 , X1          
12/16/2015 06:38:44.144 Warning WAN Availability    The network connection in use is NAT Static IP  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, 0, X1           
12/16/2015 06:38: 49.112    Alert   Firewall Event  Network Security Appliance activated
```

What can I do to solve this issue? Upgrade the firmware? Reset to factory settings? Suggestions?

Let me know if you need more information.

Thank you!

Comment: This is normal. Sonicwall appliances have a reputation for being crappy and unstable. If you have support, use it, but there are much better firewall devices on the market now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve this yourself, set up a syslog server, point the sonicwall to it, and turn the logging way up (debug level).  You can still be judicious: you probably don't need to log every firewall allow or NAT activity for this issue.  See if you can get anything useful this way.

However, I'd recommend you to just call dell/sonicwall support.  If you have access to firmware upgrades, it's likely you already have some sort of support plan with them.  This way, you won't waste a couple hours/days of your time if it turns out to be a hardware issue.

Comment: Thanks! Moreover, today, while configuring the VPN for a colleague... the SonicWall crashed multiple times. This is not a coincidence.

Comment: I strong suspect a hardware condition.  There are plenty of complaints about sonicwalls, but stability isn't usually one of them.